# can we make nested donut charts in highcharts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, dotnethighcharts

I am using highchart library .can we make nested dount chart in hightcharts ? I am able to make donut chart .I want to make nested the same thing inside the donut chart .
In other words I make donut chart can I make same thing inside the donut chart

here is my code

http://jsfiddle.net/oupmgvjy/2/

I am taking help from this
http://www.highcharts.com/demo

```
$(function () {
    Highcharts.chart('container', {
        chart: {
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: 0,
            plotShadow: false
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Browser<br>shares<br>2015',
            align: 'center',
            verticalAlign: 'middle',
            y: 40
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    distance: -50,
                    style: {
                        fontWeight: 'bold',
                        color: 'white'
                    }
                },
                startAngle: 0,
                endAngle: 270,
                center: ['50%', '75%']
            }
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'Election',
            innerSize: '85%',
            data: [
                ['a',   55],
                ['b',       65],
                 ['c',   65],
                   ['d',   132],

                {
                    name: 'Proprietary or Undetectable',
                    y: 0.2,
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: false
                    }
                }
            ]
        }]
    });
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change `data` set in series and `size` of pie

```
series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'Election',
            size: '100%',
            innerSize: '40%',
            data: [{name: "A", y: 20},
            {name: "B", y: 10},
            {name: "C", y: 15}
            ]
        }, {
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'Proprietary or Undetectable',
            innerSize: '70%',
            data: [{name: "A", y: 10},
            {name: "B", y: 15},
            {name: "C", y: 20}


            ]
        }]
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nitishkumarsingh13/v0np3qob/1/)

Comment: thanks i got it could you please tell me how to show lines http://jsfiddle.net/oupmgvjy/4/

Comment: in this example http://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-donut ...value is show with lines example "chrome v4.3" with line ..But in my example I am not able to display value with line

Comment: one more thing can I show legend http://jsfiddle.net/oupmgvjy/4/ for outer donut chart

Comment: I am able to add lines ..but I don't want lines in inner donut and no legend

Comment: legend is done thanks  for help .. can I remove inner lines ot text  A and  B http://jsfiddle.net/oupmgvjy/7/

Comment: Just add "dataLabels: {enabled: false}" in inner chart.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132881/discussion-between-nitish-kumar-and-user944513).