# Nested Donut chart with margins

Tags: highcharts, donut-chart

I am working on creating a nested donut chart  with highcharts.
I saw the below link :
[can we make nested donut charts in highcharts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41584462/can-we-make-nested-donut-charts-in-highcharts)

is there a way we can add some space/margins around each donut.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the linked example, you could do something like that:

```
  series: [{
    type: 'pie',
    name: 'Election',
    size: '60%', // Change this parameter
    innerSize: '50%', // Change this parameter
    data: [
      {name: "A", y: 20},
      {name: "B", y: 10},
      {name: "C", y: 15}
    ]
  }, {
    type: 'pie',
    name: 'Proprietary or Undetectable',
    innerSize: '80%', // Change this parameter
    data: [
      {name: "A", y: 10},
      {name: "B", y: 15},
      {name: "C", y: 20}
    ]
  }]
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/core972/gyj81pL6/2/)

Comment: Thank you so much , really appreciate the help.

Comment: @Sarah, If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.